# How to set widgets to link to array for jupyternotebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, interpolation, ipywidgets

I am trying to set an interactive notebook up that plots some interpolated GPS data. I have the plotting working by itself, but I am trying to use the ipython widgets to make it more interactive for others.

Currently, my plotting looks like this

```
def create_grid(array,spacing=.01):
    '''
    creates evenly spaced grid from the min and max of an array
    '''
    grid = np.arange(np.amin(array), np.amax(array),spacing)
    return grid
def interpolate(x, y, z, grid_spacing = .01, model='spherical',returngrid = False):
    '''Interpolates z value and uses create_grid to create a grid of values based on min and max of x and y'''
    grid_x = create_grid(x,spacing = grid_spacing)
    grid_y = create_grid(y, spacing = grid_spacing)
    OK = OrdinaryKriging(x, y, z, variogram_model=model, verbose = False,\
                    enable_plotting=False, nlags = 20)
    z1, ss1 = OK.execute('grid', grid_x,grid_y,mask = False)
    print('Interpolation Complete')
    vals=np.ma.getdata(z1)
    sigma = np.ma.getdata(ss1)
    if returngrid == False:
        return vals,sigma
    else:
        return vals, sigma, grid_x, grid_y

mesh_x, mesh_y = np.meshgrid(grid_x,grid_y)
plot = plt.scatter(mesh_x, mesh_y, c = z1, cmap = cm.hsv)
cb = plt.colorbar(plot)
cb.set_label('Northing Change')

plt.show()
```

'''

This works currently, but I am trying to set up a widget to change the variogram model in the kriging interpolation, as well as change the field to be interpolated.

Currently, to do that I have:

```
def update_plot(zfield,variogram):
    plt.clf()
    z1, ss1, grid_x,grid_y =interpolate(lon,lat,zfield,returngrid= True,model=variogram)
    mesh_x, mesh_y = np.meshgrid(grid_x,grid_y)
    plot = plt.scatter(mesh_x, mesh_y, c = z1, cmap = cm.hsv)
    cb = plot.colorbar(plot)
    cb.set_label('Interpolated Value')


variogram = widgets.Dropdown(options = ['linear',  'power',  'gaussian', 'spherical',  'exponential',  'hole-effect'],
                            value = 'spherical', description = "Variogram model for interpolation")
zfield = widgets.Dropdown(options = {'Delta N':delta_n, 'Delta E': delta_e,'Delta V':delta_v},value = 'Delta N', 
                          description = 'Interpolated value')
widgets.interactive(update_plot, variogram = variogram,zfield =zfield)
```

Which brings up the error

TraitError: Invalid selection: value not found

the values delta_n, delta_e and delta_v are numpy arrays. I have tried looking at documentation but it is not as detailed as something like matplotlibs documentation or something so I feel like I am kind of flying blind here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In this line, you specify the possible values of the Dropdown as:

```
zfield = widgets.Dropdown(options = {'Delta N':delta_n, 'Delta E': delta_e,'Delta V':delta_v}
```

When a mapping is used, the values of the dict are interpreted as the possible options. So `value = 'Delta N'` causes an error as this is not one of the possible values of the Dropdown (although it is one of the keys in the mapping dict). I believe you want `value = delta_n` instead.

Comment: The same error occurs when I do this. I also tried putting the dict into a variable 'vals_dict' and then calling 'value = vals_dict.values()' and I get the same error.